# Javascript Data list coming out empty but not errors in the console

Tags: javascript

I have some data with which I'm creating 2 arrays.

The console is giving me no errors but the lists are both empty.

Here is the data

```
mydata = {
    "id": "661",
    "name": "some name",
    "description": "some desc",
    "subcat": {
        "662": {
            "id": "662",
            "name": "sub 1",
            "translations": null
        },
        "663": {
            "id": "663",
            "name": "sub 2",
            "translations": null
        }
    },
    "image": null
};
```

Here is the code:

```
chList=[];
thList=[];
thCount=[];

for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {

    var obj = mydata[i];

    var cl = obj.name;

    if (obj.subcat != null) {
        chList.push(cl);
    }

    if(obj.subcat) {

        if (i < 10) {

            var nme = obj.subcat.map( function(item){
                return item.name;
                console.log(nme);
            });

            thList = thList.concat(nme);
            thCount.push(nme.length);
        }

    }

}

console.log(thList);
console.log(thCount);
```

The problem is that both thList and thCount are coming out empty like this: []

How can I corrent this?

Comment: `mydata` is not an array, so looping until an undefined `length` property value will not do much.

Comment: mydata is not array. It is object it have not length property.

Comment: Yoy can use var length = Object.keys(mydata); And you get length of mydata

Comment: Are you maybe confusing `mydata` and the similar objects you have collected in an array? Your code looks like it expects to find `subcat` several times...

Comment: @trincot Yes, it does ... one of the lists needs to get all subcat names and the other count the subcut records in each

Comment: OK, see my answer which takes that into account.

Comment: @trincot just going one question ... please see under your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you expect `mydata` to be an array of objects, not just the one you presented. Your code will run better if you wrap the presented object literal for  `mydata` inside an array, with possibly other similar objects added to it.

Secondly, `obj.subcat.map` will not work, as `subcat` is not an array either. You should apply `map` to `Object.keys(obj.subcat)` instead, and then access `obj.subcat` by the keys you get.

With these two adjustments it works:

```js
// mydata is an array
mydata = [{
    "id": "661",
    "name": "some name",
    "description": "some desc",
    "subcat": {
        "662": {
            "id": "662",
            "name": "sub 1",
            "translations": null
        },
        "663": {
            "id": "663",
            "name": "sub 2",
            "translations": null
        }
    },
    "image": null
}];

var chList=[];
var thList=[];
var thCount=[];

for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    var obj = mydata[i];
    var cl = obj.name;
    if (obj.subcat != null) {
        chList.push(cl);
    }
    if(obj.subcat) {
        if (i < 10) {
            // You cannot use map on an object directly. Use Object.keys:
            var nme = Object.keys(obj.subcat).map( function(key){
                var item = obj.subcat[key]; // get the item by key
                return item.name;
                // NB: console.log after `return` does not get executed!
            });
            thList = thList.concat(nme);
            // cf. Follow-up question: repeat length as many times:
            thCount = thCount.concat(Array(nme.length).fill(nme.length));
        }
    }
}

console.log(thList);
console.log(thCount);
```

Comment: OK, it's almost perfect. I just need thCount to get counted everytime so for each sub I need a count. In this example it's would be sub 1, sub 2 ...then 2 , 2 ... basically the amount of counts need to match the list so in this case it would just count it twice as the same count

Comment: That really is a different question, but OK, I updated the code to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

`mydata.length` is undefined as you are trying to access the `length` property which doesn't exist on the Object `myData`. So, the loop iteration never works and hence your arrays `thList , thCount` are always empty.

The `length` property exists on Array in Javascript and when you try to access any property which is not a part of that object, javascript returns `undefined`

If you are trying to get the properties of the object then you can try iterating over the enumerable properties like

```
for (var property in mydata ) {
    if (mydata.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // Rest of your statements
    }
}
```

Also, Statement like `var obj = mydata[i];` would not work in your case as the `mydata` is not array. If you define `mydata` as an array then statement `var obj = mydata[i];` can work.

Comment: I'm confused of what parts of the code will still work and which I need to replace :o/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The variable names are not descriptive enough to express clearly as to what is required from this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get length of mydata, use Object.keys method

```
var length = Object.keys(mydata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

```
for (var key in yourobject) {
    // and access your data like this 
    yourobject[key].whatever
}
```